# select data from users tables according to sender, recipient id's in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble formatting this SQL query correctly. What I'm trying to do is select data from an activity table and data from two user's who's ID's are stored in that activity table. My current statement looks like this:

```
SELECT activity.id, activity.sender, activity.recipient, activity.amount, activity.description, activity.create_date, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.username, users.profile_photo FROM `activity` INNER JOIN `users` ON users.id = activity.sender ORDER BY activity.create_date DESC
```

Now this grabs the data for activity.sender user, but I'm looking to extends my query to include the activity.recipient user. I have played around with different things such as a "GROUP BY activity.recipient, activity.sender" and GROUP_CONCAT(users.first_name, users.last_name, etc..), but have had no success.

Updated query:

```
SELECT activity.id, activity.sender, activity.recipient, activity.amount, activity.description, activity.create_date, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.username, users.profile_photo, recipient.first_name, recipient.last_name, recipient.username FROM `activity` INNER JOIN `users` ON users.id = activity.sender INNER JOIN 'users' AS recipient ON activity.recipient = recipient.id ORDER BY activity.create_date DESC
```

Still getting SQL syntax error: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'users\' AS recipient ON activity.recipient = recipient.id ORDER BY activity.crea\' at line 1'

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you are asking, but I'll give it a shot.

I think you need to include the User table twice in your query, once to look-up the sender and second time to lookup the receiver. If so, the query would look something like this

```
SELECT activity.*, users.*, receiver_user.first_name, receiver_user.last_name
FROM `activity`  INNER JOIN `users` 
        ON users.id = activity.sender 
      inner join 'users' as 'receiver_user'
        ON activity.recipient = users.id
ORDER BY activity.create_date DESC
```

Note that I used an *alias* for your users table, to wit, "inner join 'users' as 'receiver_user'. Also note that I know lots of SQL but not much mySql, so the quotes might be wrong.

Comment: Interesting idea. This still gives my SQL syntax error though. I am getting this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'users\' AS recipient ON activity.recipient = recipient.id ORDER BY activity.crea\' at line 1." I'll update question with current query, based off your answer.

Comment: Hi Ryne - the syntax issue pertains to MsQL, not SQL in general, but it could be a couple different things. First try taking out the word 'AS'. Second, try messing with adding quotes around recipient. If that doesn't work, look the syntax for using aliases in MySql